# Issue with SpreadJS selenium automation

Tags: selenium, automation, spreadjs

I am trying to automate spreadJS application using selenium web driver java. I have found something like this,

```
js.executeScript("var spread = new GcSpread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById('ss'));");
```

And I tried the same after launching the browser from eclipse. Do we need to  add any JavaScript libraries for this since it is showing the error as GcSpread not defined.

Comment: did you add the SJS script referenced to the page?

Comment: Hi team, Could you please tell me where we can add the reference.? how we can get the reference? I have created the below codes  driver.get("https://www.grapecity.com/demos/spread/JS/TutorialSample/Showcase/financialKPIs/purejs");
  js.executeScript("window.testSpread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.findControl(document.querySelector(\"[gcuielement=\'gcSpreaad\']\"))");
    /* get value of cell 0, 0 of active sheet */
    js.executeScript("return window.testSpread.getActiveSheet().getValue(0,0);");     The DOM object  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ss']"))  is also returning null for me

Comment: This is working fine..there was an iframe which was creating the problem. Thank you